Understanding the Terminology of Closed Subsets in $GL(n, \mathbb{C})$
In the context of the general linear group $GL(n, \mathbb{C})$, we use specific terminology to describe closed subsets. I'm paying attention to two definitions, which I report here and which come from the book Hall, Brian, Lie groups, Lie algebras, and representations. An elementary introduction, Graduate Texts in Mathematics 222. Cham: Springer (ISBN 978-3-319-13466-6/hbk; 978-3-319-13467-3/ebook). xiii, 449 p. (2015). ZBL1316.22001.
We say that a subset $G \subset GL(n, \mathbb{C})$ is closed in $GL(n, \mathbb{C})$ if for any sequence of matrices $A_m$ in $G$ that converges to a matrix $A$, the matrix $A$ must either belong to $G$ or be non-invertible.
On the other hand, we say that $G \subset GL(n, \mathbb{C})$ is closed in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ if $A_m$ converging to a matrix $A$ implies $A \in G$.
My confusion arises from the intuition that these terms might be reversed: the word "closed" suggests that the limit should necessarily be within the group. Why do we use this specific nomenclature? Could you provide some insight into the rationale behind adopting this terminology, especially when the intuitive understanding seems to imply the opposite?

It’s just the usual subspace topology on $GL(n)$, which is of course not closed in $M_n$. It’s about closed topological subspaces, not closure under an operation.

Consider the space $(0,\infty)$, with its usual distance (or its usual topology, if you prefer). And consider the subset $(0,1]$. It's a closed subset, in spite of the fact that the sequence $(1/n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ of elements of $(0,1]$ converges to $0$. Since $0$ is outside $(0,1]$, that's not a problem. But if you were working on $\Bbb R$, rather than working on $(0,\infty)$, then $(0,1]$ would not be a closed subset anymore.
It's the same thing with a subgroup $G$ of $GL(n,\Bbb C)$. If a sequence $(A_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ of elements of $G$ converges to some element of $M_n(\Bbb C)\setminus G$, that's not a problem, in the sense that $G$ may still be closed. For instance, if $n=2$, $G$ is the group of upper triangular matrices and,  for each $n\in\Bbb N$, $A_n=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1/n&0\\0&1/n\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, then the sequence $(A_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges to the zero matrix. Nevertheless, that is compatible with the fact that $G$ is closed, since the zero matrix lies outside $GL(2,\Bbb C)$.

I understood all the definitions. I asked about the terminology... Since "closed" intuitively suggests that a limit is in the set, that is, $G$ closed in $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ should suggest that $A$ is only invertible instead saying that $G$ closed in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ should suggest that $A$ is just in $G$. It is more a curiosity than a mathematical question

As my first example show, your intuition is not correct.
